# Adjectif pour une personne ne remettant pas assez en cause ce qu'elle pense savoir

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Je cherche un adjectif (de préférence) pour qualifier quelqu'un qui *ne remet jamais rien en question*. Non pas que cette personne ne conteste jamais rien, mais plutôt qu'elle reste convaincue sans vraiment jamais vraiment prendre le temps d'y penser.

Je vois bien "*borné*", mais "borné" sous-entendent (à mon sens) qu'il y a un coté conscient. Je cherche un équivalent inconscient de "borné" sans pour autant parler de naïveté ni d'innocence. Car quelqu'un de naïf, peut, même s'il se pose des questions, ne se rend jamais compte qu'il se trompe. Dans l'idéal ici le terme n'impliquerait que le manque de questionnement et non la capacité de réflexion en elle-même.

On pourrait par exemple utiliser cet adjectif pour qualifier une personne rejoignant une secte dans un moment difficile de sa vie et qui resterait attachée à cette secte.

Désolé, ce n'est pas très clair, c'est justement pour ça que je cherche ce fameux mot. Et pas d'inquiétude, l'exemple que je donne ici est purement fictif :).

Si vous connaissez un mot qui se rapproche je suis preneur. D'ailleurs un mot en anglais/italien/espagnol irait aussi si par hasard vous n'êtes pas francophone.

Comment: Si je comprends bien, ce n'est pas l'enrôlement dans la secte que vous cherchez à qualifier (on pourrait alors dire _influençable_ ou _manipulable_) mais l'attachement qui lui succède. C'est bien ça?

Comment: concernant l'exemple de la secte, pourrais-tu faire une phrase à trou où il s'agirait de remplir le trou par l'adjectif? Cela permettrait de mieux comprendre ce que tu cherches.

Comment: Hmm quelque chose comme "Cela fera dix ans aujourd'hui qu'il a rejoint cette secte, trop ... pour se rendre compte que c'est elle qui a détruit sa vie ... ". Ici aveugle pourrait être ce qui se rapproche le plus de ce que je cherche, sans vraiment me satisfaire non plus car trop vague.

Comment: Dans l'exemple de la secte, je pense que "fortement endoctriné" remplirait bien le trou. Mais ça ne convient qu'à ce cas précis, alors que la question me semble chercher une réponse générale. Et j'ai un doute : dans l'exemple de la secte, il est clair que l'adjectif recherché qualifie un état dû aux circonstances vécues par la personne concernée. Or la question cite "quelqu'un qui ne remet __jamais__ rien en question" : si je me fie à "jamais", il s'agirait plutôt d'un état qui fait intrinsèquement partie de son caractère. Quelle est la bonne interprétation de ce qu'on cherche ?

Comment: As I understand the concept, in English I’d [jokingly] compare such a quality in a person to “quick/hard-setting putty [in their hands],” with the “putty [in their hands]” part trying to capture the person’s initial malleability/impressionability/gullibility & the “quick/hard-setting” part trying to capture his/her resistance/inability to break that initial, now hardened mold. However, I can’t think of any adjectives that cover these two notions in one word in either language & I don’t even know how to translate my "suggestion" into French (comme l’argile à séchage rapide [dans leurs mains]?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pas d'adjectif en vue mais des expressions se rapportant au sens :

> - mouton de Parnurge
> - veau (*les français sont des veaux*)
> - manquer de discernement, de sens critique, de jugeote
> - avoir des œillères
> - gober

Comment: Merci ! "Avoir des œillères" est ce qui se rapproche le plus de ce que je cherche. Je serais quand même intéressé par quelque chose de plus passe partout (moins imagé).

Answer (score 2):

Dans le cas d'une secte, l'expression

> vouer une confiance aveugle

ou toutes les déclinaisons telles que

> croire aveuglément

seraient un bon choix, bien que ce ne soient pas des adjectifs.

Il peut également être bon de combiner un adverbe à un adjectif, d'une façon inhabituelle, telle que :

> Aveuglément loyal
>
> Aveuglément fidèle

A noter que, selon le contexte, les adjectifs "loyal" et "fidèle" peuvent avoir une connotation très péjorative, comparant la personne à un animal.

Du reste, l'adjectif "sectaire" existe, mais a un sens assez loin de l'idée de naïveté. De [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sectaire) (le site du Larouse empêchant le copier-coller) :

> Celui qui professe des opinions étroites, intolérantes et violentes.

Answer (score 2):

Quelqu'un de borné ne l'est pas forcément de manière consciente, ça peut simplement être un trait de caractère. quelques synonymes sont: *buté*, *obstiné*, *têtu*... Dans tous les cas on fait référence à la force que déploie la personne pour ne pas dériver de son mode de pensée.
Presque synonymes, on a:

- *étroit d'esprit* : on met davantage en cause les capacités de la personne à appréhender un autre point de vue que sa bonne volonté.
- *snob* : ici la personne refuse par mépris de recevoir une opinion différente.

Comment: "fait référence à la force que déploie la personne pour ne pas dériver de son mode de pensée" c'est ce que je voulais dire par "conscient", dans l'idéal le mot serait plus proche de "fait référence à l'absence de force déployée par la personne empêchant ainsi l'évolution de son mode de pensée"

Answer (score 1):

L'adjectif qui me semble le meilleur est

> Naïf

Voir aussi

> Simplet
>   Crédule

Answer (score 1):

Est ce que "dogmatique" correspondrait ?

Comment: On est dans le même ordre d'idée, mais le dogmatique ajoute une notion importante: celle d'*imposer* les idées en questions à d'autres.

Answer (score 1):

Je peux vous proposer:

- obtus
- obstiné
- naïf
- crédule
- dogmatique

Vous pouvez renverser la situation et dire qu'à ses yeux toutes ses croyances sont indubitables.